# pylint error message on cloud 9 CS50

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, pylint

I'm following the CS50 course and am having a problem with application.py.  I was getting the following warnings in the Cloud 9 code editor (Ace):

```
instance of SQLAlchemy has no column member
instance of SQLAlchemy has no integer member
instance of SQLAlchemy has no text member
instance of scoped_session has no add member
instance of scoped_session has no commit member
Class Registrants has no query member
```

I created a file .pylintrc in the home directory and added the following two lines:

```
ignored-modules=flask_sqlalchemy
ignored-classes=SQLObject,Registrant
```

This got rid of most of the errors but I'm left with:

```
instance of scoped_session has no add member
instance of scoped_session has no commit member
```

Here's the code that causing the problem:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, request, url_for
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)

# Flask-SQLAlchemy
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:///froshims3.db"
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_ECHO"] = True
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Registrant(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "registrants"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Text)
    dorm = db.Column(db.Text)

    def __init__(self, name, dorm):
        self.name = name
        self.dorm = dorm

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/register", methods=["POST"])
def register():
    if request.form["name"] == "" or request.form["dorm"] == "":
        return render_template("failure.html")
    registrant = Registrant(request.form["name"], request.form["dorm"])
    db.session.add(registrant)
    db.session.commit()
    return render_template("success.html")

@app.route("/registrants")
def registrants():
    rows = Registrant.query.all()
    return render_template("registrants.html", registrants=rows)

@app.route("/unregister", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def unregister():
    if request.method == "GET":
        rows = Registrant.query.all()
        return render_template("unregister.html", registrants=rows)
    elif request.method == "POST":
        if request.form["id"]:
            Registrant.query.filter(Registrant.id ==    request.form["id"]).delete()
            db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for("registrants"))
```

Answer (score 5):

needed to add in the .pylintrc file:

```
ignored-classes=SQLObject,Registrant,scoped_session
```

apparently Python is creating some classes at run time and pylint isn't able to pick that information up.

Not really happy with this answer as it ignores the problem rather than fixes it.  If anyone has a better solution please let me know.  The Staff at CS50 is looking into this but no other solution yet.

Answer (score 2):

Using VSCode I had to add the following item in the **Python › Linting: Pylint Args** settings.

```
--ignored-classes=SQLObject,Registrant,scoped_session
```